# Can I apply for a B1 B2 visa while I'm in the US?

Tags: b1-b2-visas

I am presently employed by staffing agency in the Philippines as a US-based coordinator to their client in the US. I am the company representative of our agency in the Philippines. During my stay in US, our client is responsible for my stay. I have a valid B1-B2 visa but it is soon to expire on July 2017. Can I apply for B1-B2 visa while I am in the US?

Comment: How long are you expecting your stay in the US to be?

Comment: Also, when do you plan to arrive in the US?

Answer (score 1):

Short answer: You cannot apply for any US visa while being in the US.

But note that the US is special in the sense that they only require you to have a valid visa to *enter* the country. As always, the visa of course has to be suitable for the purpose of the visit.